# How should I backup my realtime data? Is there a better solution?

Tags: c++, backup

### Question

How should I backup the real-time data in my program?  I'm currently using the memory mapped files provided by the "Interprocess" library in C++ Boost.  I wonder is there a better alternative solution?

### More Details

My program periodically receives real-time data from hardware equipments and store the data into a fixed-size buffer.  Usually the period is short, say, 3 seconds.  Because the buffer is important, **I want to backup it so in case that my program crashes, it could restore to the original state before it crashed.**

**I do it this way:** Estimate the maximum size of the buffer and create a memory mapped file in the same size.  Bind the in-memory buffer and the mapped file, so when the memory is changed, the change would be written to the local file immediately.

When the program recovers from a crash, it simply reads the mapped file and deserialize the data.

This solution **works fine based on some pre-conditions**:
1). The quantity of data is known in advance: 3 data items or 5 items.
2). Each data item size is fixed in advance(in C/C++ langugage, this means a fixed-size struct/class).

However, I'm foreseeing **something to happen in my project that may break these pre-conditions:**
1). **The data item quantity might change during the system run-time.**  The customer may start to use more hardware equipments so there will be more data to be received.  This means I need to recreate the mapped file, replicate the old data, and start to store the new.  This may bring in a performance issue.
2). **The size of some special data cannot be determined in advance**, for example, some description information entered by the user.

So: **How do you backup the data in your program?**
I wonder if **there is a better solution than the memory mapped file?**